# Clarification needed: Wrath of the Lich King - A Pandemic System board game

Tags: cooperation, world-of-warcraft-wrath-of-the-lich

Recently we started playing "[World of Warcraft: Wrath of the Lich King - A Pandemic System Board Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/342848/world-warcraft-wrath-lich-king)", but after reading the rulebook a couple of time we still had some questions.

There are some situations not described in the rulebook about the "Abominations", when he moves and enters the space you're standing on he deals 1 damage.
But what happens when:

- you enter a space with an Abomination on it?
- the Abomination spawns on your space?
- you and an Abomination are standing on the same space when you must "Activate Abominations"?

And some texts on the cards seem ambiguous, maybe this is because we are not native english speakers.

The "Heal" card reads:

> Any hero on your space rests and heals +1

Does this mean "each hero" (this is how Google translates this for us) or "a hero"?

The "Fight" card reads:

> + to any fight on your space

Does this mean "each fight for the duration of your turn" (so possibly the full 4 actions, again Google translates this as "each fight") or "a single fight"?

And while I'm at it, the "Defend" card does not specify the damage source, so here we also allow damage from questing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abomination activate during step 4 "Activate Abominations". They don't activate when players move or during spawn or any time other than "Activate Abominations". See p. 8 of the rulebook.

> ### Activate Abominations
>
> One at a time, each abomination
> moves 1 space toward the closest
> hero, then deals 1 damage to 1
> hero on its space. If multiple
> heroes are tied for closest, the
> current player chooses which of
> the tied heroes the abomination
> moves toward.
> After moving, if there are multiple
> heroes on an abomination’s
> space, the current player chooses
> which hero is dealt damage.
> If multiple abominations deal
> damage to the same hero, they
> deal damage simultaneously (so
> the hero can play 1 “Defend” card
> to prevent the damage from multiple abominations).

If it's already in the same space as a hero, then it doesn't move (since it can't move any closer, there is no path "toward" that hero).

Echoed in [this BGG post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2753790/abominations-movement) and [this BGG post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2785360/during-activate-abominations-if-they-are-already-y).

### Heal

The Heal cards allows you to heal any (one) hero on your space, not "every" hero on your space.

Compare Travel, which also uses "any" and allows you to move any (one) Hero on your space, not all heroes on your space.

### Fight

The fight card affects the current action (fight).

### Defend

Yes, it can prevent quest damage.

Echoed in [this BGG post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2786089/using-defend-card-block-quest-damage-playing-solo).